# Catching uncaught exceptions through django development server

Tags: python, django, debugging

I am looking for some way in django's development server that will make the server to stop at any uncaught exception automatically, as it is done with pdb mode in ipython console.

I know to put import pdb; pdb.set_trace() lines into the code to make application stop. But this doesn't help me, because the line where the exception is thrown is being called too many times. So I can't find out the exact conditions to define a conditional break point.

Is this possible?

Thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `sys.excepthook` to a function that does `import pdb; pdb.pm()`, as per [this recipe](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/0596001673/pythoncook-CHP-14-SECT-6).

Comment: Somehow I can't override sys.excepthook:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261668/cannot-override-sys-excepthook
Is this normal?

Comment: @Mert, as I explained answering that question, ipython (which in that question you mention you're using) is different. So either run `ipython -pdb`, or plain `python` which this excepthook override.

Comment: @Alex, Thanks for the explanation.
I have one more question:
I can catch any uncaught exception through overriding sys.excepthook when I run a python script. That's good.
But this recipe doesn't work when I run django server. The exception is caught and logged by django. 
Is it possible to make pdb catch the exception?

Comment: Ok, I got it. Django's debug module catches and logs any uncaught exception. pdb doesn't catch the exception because the recipe makes pdb to catch any uncaught exception, not caught exceptions.

Comment: @Mert, yep. There are actually ways to hook up a debugger, esp. if you're running django on WSGI, see http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DebuggingTechniques -- but setting sys.excepthook is still all about uncaught exceptions.

Comment: I have just found Werkzeug tool. That is very useful for debugging where an exception occurs. http://ericholscher.com/blog/2008/aug/28/screencast-debugging-django-error-page/