# Make IPython look like a normal python shell

Tags: python, ipython

My largest issue is the fancy IPython exceptions. I want them look like normal python
exceptions, but when I try to reset `sys.excepthook` it does not work:

```
In [31]: import sys; sys.excepthook = sys.__excepthook__; (sys.excepthook, sys.__excepthook__)
Out[31]: 
(<bound method TerminalInteractiveShell.excepthook of <IPython.terminal.interactiveshell.TerminalInteractiveShell object at 0x27c8e10>>,
 <function sys.excepthook>)
```

Comment: It's readonly, I believe.

Comment: Hmm, couldn't find anywhere in the docs anything indicating that... Is there no indirect way to change it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IPython replaces `sys.excepthook` each time you execute a line of code, rendering it pointless to change it each time. In addition to this, IPython catches all exceptions and handles them itself, without having to invoke `sys.excepthook`.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28758396/4909087) to a related question provides a way of overriding this behaviour: Basically, you've to override Ipython's `showtraceback` function with one that will format and display your exception the way you want it.

```
def showtraceback(self):
    traceback_lines = traceback.format_exception(*sys.exc_info())
    del traceback_lines[1]
    message = ''.join(traceback_lines)
    sys.stderr.write(message)

import sys
import traceback
import IPython
IPython.core.interactiveshell.InteractiveShell.showtraceback = showtraceback
```